# Transformation Matrices

Tags: matrices

How can I determine a 2x2 trasformation matrix which transforms the triangle with vertices (1,0), (-1,0), and (2,-1) to a triangle with vertices (1,1), (-1,-2), and (3,-2)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not about TeX & friends. I reccommend migration to Maths.SX.

Comment: If SE moderators confuse _Mathematica_ and _Mathematics_ no wonder why some users do the same..

Comment: I said before we should change the name of this forum to Wolfram Language, but no body listens to me.

Comment: Sorry for posting an answer...hmmm

Answer (score 2):

If the question is how to do this with `Mathematica` then this particular problem can be done using  default `FindGeometricTransform` (documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html)). In this case it can be solved exactly.

For this particular example:

```
pts1 = {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {2, -1}};
pts2 = {{1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {3, -2}};
tr = Chop[FindGeometricTransform[pts2, pts1]]
```

This yields:

[image]

The transform function can be decomposed using `CoefficientArrays`

```
{t, m} = Normal /@ CoefficientArrays[tr[[2]][{x, y}]]
```

where `t` is translation vector and `m` is transform matrix.

The result can be tested:

```
m.# + t & /@ pts1
```

yields:

{{1., 1.}, {-1., 2.}, {3., -2.}}

as desired

Or plotted:

```
ListPlot[{pts2, tr[[2]][#] & /@ pts1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.03]}, {Green, PointSize[0.02]}}]
```

[image]

More complex pairs of sets of points and contexts would need deeper consideration (rigid, shear, etc). I again refer you to the documentation.